# how to implement distributed database in pg admin3

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Hi i would like to know how to setup distributed database using pg admin 3 , so that our team can view database changes without importing and exporting to their machine.I have done the same method in mysql, but how can i done this using postgreSQL and pg admin 3.

Comment: Install Postgres on a central server and let everybody access that server (btw: pgAdmin has nothing to do with this, this is a pure Postgres setup/install problem)

Comment: do you have any tutorial for that?

Comment: Apparently you already know how to install Postgres - just install it on a server that everyone can connect to.